# How to securely encrypt many similiar chunks of data with the same key?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm writing an application that will require the following security features: when launching the CLI version, you should pass some key to it. Some undefined number of chunks of data of the same size will be generated. It needs to be stored remotely. This will be a sensitive data. I want it to be encrypted and accessible only by that one key that was passed to it initially. My question is, **which algorithm will suit me**? I [read about AES](http://www.itworld.com/article/2693828/data-protection/a-basic-encryption-strategy-for-storing-sensitive-data.html) but it says that

> When you perform an encryption operation you initialize your Encryptor
>   with this key, then generate a new, unique Initialization Vector for
>   each record you’re going to encrypt.

which means I'll have to pass a key and an IV, rather than just the key and this IV should be unique for each generated chunk of data (and there is going to be a lot of those).

If the answer is AES, *which* encryption mode is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any **modern** symmetric algorithm.  The amount of data and how to handle your IVs is irrelevant because it applies no matter which symmetric algorithm you pick.

AES-128 is a good choice, as it isn't limited by law in the US and 128 bits is infeasible to brute force.  If you aren't in the US, you could use AES-256 if you wanted to, but implementations in Java require additional installations.

You say you are going to generate n many chunks of data (or retrieve, whatever).

You *could* encrypt them all at once in CBC mode, which keeps AES as a block cipher, and you'll only end up with one IV.  You'll need an HMAC here to protect the integrity.  This isn't the most modern way, however.

You *should* use AES in GCM mode as a stream cipher.  You'll still have one single IV (nounce) but the ciphertext will also be authenticated.

IVs should be generated randomly and prepended to the ciphertext.  You can then retrieve the IV when it is time to decrypt.  Remember: IVs aren't secret, they just need to be random!

EDIT: As pointed out below, IVs should be generated using a crypto-secure random number generator.  IVs for CTR based modes, like GCM, only need to be unique.

In summary, what you are worried about shouldn't be worried about.  One key is fine.  More than one IV is fine too, but there are ways to do it with just one.  You will have to worry about IVs either way.  Don't use ECB mode.

Comment: I would just add that IVs for CBC mode should be generated using a cryptographic prng (for example, SecureRandom).  For GCM mode, the requirement is less strict: you only need to assure not repeating the IV/nonce.